# SICP (MIT-Scheme) Square Root procedure

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, mit-scheme

I'm attempting to go through the SICP book, and I've run into a problem trying to implement the Square root method laid out in the book.

My code:

```
(define (square-root-loop g x)
  (if (good-enough? g x)
   g
   (squre-root-loop (improve-sqrt-guess g x)
           x)))

(define (improve-sqrt-guess g x)
  (average-guess g (/ x g)))

(define (average-guess x y)
    (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (good-enough? g x)
  (< (abs (- (square g) x)) 0.001))

(define (sqrt x)
  (square-root-loop 1.0 x))
```

However, when I call the sqrt procedure, eg: (sqrt 9) , I get the following error:

```
;Unbound variable: squre-root-loop
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 11) => Specify a value to use instead of squre-root-loop.
; (RESTART 10) => Define squre-root-loop to a given value.
; (RESTART 9) => Return to read-eval-print level 9.
; (RESTART 8) => Return to read-eval-print level 8.
; (RESTART 7) => Return to read-eval-print level 7.
; (RESTART 6) => Return to read-eval-print level 6.
; (RESTART 5) => Return to read-eval-print level 5.
; (RESTART 4) => Return to read-eval-print level 4.
; (RESTART 3) => Return to read-eval-print level 3.
; (RESTART 2) => Return to read-eval-print level 2.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

The code is pretty much exactly as it is in the book, so I don't what's up. (I have passed the procedures to the Evaluator after defining them, so they should be defined. 'abs' has already been defined as well.)

I'm running MIT-Scheme on emacs. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUw0N.png)

Comment: There is a typo: you have written `squre-root-loop` instead of `square-root-loop`.

Comment: @Renzo oh my god, I cannot believe I didn't catch that wtf. I think I need to step back from the screen for today.  
Thank you so much!

Comment: And to suppliant: `+` and other names put in operator position are just variables. If you evaluate `+` you get the procedure object that is used by apply. With that in mind the error message is spot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, I will write up a formal answer instead of having the answer as a comment.

The problems are that 
(1) `square-root-loop` is spelled incorrectly in the recursive call,
it is referred to as `squre-root-loop`;
(2) `square` is missing, it should be defined as `(define (square x) (* x x))`.

Be careful of the naming.
The functions are both named `sqrt` and `square-root`, use the same name.
So, `square-root-loop` should be `sqrt-loop`.

Some of the function names include reference to square root, others don't.
Apparently, SICP doesn't introduce `letrec` until very late, but when you learn about it, try to gather the functions into an inner scope and let only the outer function mention square root to avoid redundancy.